# Can a sharingan be regenerated?

Tags: naruto

I remember that Naruto healed Kakashi's eye. If he did that to Sasuke if he lost his eye, would the Sharingan regenerate along with his eye, or would he be left with just a regular eye?

Comment: Naruto didn't "healed" Kakashi eye but made another from his cells, it's not good example for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "regenerated" you mean like Sasuke could get his rinnegan back after Boruto stabbed it out then no, But if you mean if kid Kakashi had a Sharingan, and then got his eye slashed then yes. What I mean is that if an eye is slashed and not stabbed out, a strong medical ninjutsu specialist could heal it.